# Cordova - App not installed after zipalign

Tags: android, cordova, apk

I have successfully signed apk file and when I installed the apk on the device it worked fine. Then I ran this command:

```
zipalign -v 4 android-release.apk FileName.apk
```

and at the end I got the message "Verification successful"

When I tried to install that apk on the device I got an error " App not installed".

I don't know what could cause this problem.

**Edit 1:**

When I tried to upload apk that is optimized with zipalign I got an error:

> You uploaded an APK with an invalid signature (learn more about
>   signing). Error from apksigner: ERROR (Jar signer CERT.RSA): JAR
>   signature META-INF/CERT.SF indicates the APK is signed using APK
>   Signature Scheme v2 but no such signature was found. Signature
>   stripped?

And the apk that hasn't been optimized with zipalign can be uploaded on play store.

**Edit 2:**

The problem could be that I had signed an APK file before I optimized it with zipalign.

As soon as I test it I will post the update here.

Comment: Hi mishke any luck resolving this issue??

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've found that for Android 5 and under you have to zipalign AFTER apksign Android 6 works either way, and Android 7 only works if you apksign AFTER zipalign.